# Exception in masstransit and masstransit.autofac libraries after downgraded the version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, masstransit

well the problem is that for now by system requirements I have to implement masstransit with autofac to use azure bus, what happens is that at first I used version 7.2.1 of masstransit, after that I downgraded to version 5.5.6 of masstransit together with the masstransit.autofac and azure service bus libraries.

I had to rewrite much of the code and I have no errors in showing me the visual studio, but at the time of starting the bus I have this problem, which I think is more related to the change of libraries:

```
{"Method 'ResolveComponent' in type 'MassTransit.AutofacIntegration.LifetimeScopeRegistry`1' 
    from assembly 'MassTransit.AutofacIntegration, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa' does not have an implementation.":
    "MassTransit.AutofacIntegration.LifetimeScopeRegistry`1"}
    System.Exception {System.TypeLoadException}
```

Some part of the code where I use the "resolve" is here, although I am not sure if it is related:

```
var container = CreatorContainer.ConfigureContainer();
                if (CreatorContainer.isThereBusConfig)
                {
                    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope()) 
                    {
                        var azureBus = scope.Resolve<IBusControl>();
                        var liveScheduleUpdateData = new LiveScheduleUpdateMessage();
                        liveScheduleUpdateData.MappingKey = this.teamIdentityProvider.GetIdentity().MappingKey;
                        liveScheduleUpdateData.Job = job;
                        liveScheduleUpdateData.LiveSchedule = schedFound;
                        liveScheduleUpdateData.PunchAction = punchType;
                        liveScheduleUpdateData.User = employee;
                        liveScheduleUpdateData.PunchRequest = request;
                        liveScheduleUpdateData.Offset = offset;
                        azureBus.Publish<LiveScheduleUpdateMessage>(liveScheduleUpdateData);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                    {
                        var winTeamApplication = scope.Resolve<IWinTeamApplication>();
                        winTeamApplication.LiveScheduleUpdate(this.teamIdentityProvider.GetIdentity().MappingKey, job, schedFound, punchType, employee, request, offset);
                    }
                }
```

sda

Comment: I'm unsure how much this will help, but have you tried build cleaning the solution and build cleaning all of the included projects? And then rebuild the solution and see if it compiles for you. It may be that some of the residual dlls are leftover.  Good luck!

Comment: @MarcusParsons yeah, I try it and not work

Comment: You have mismatched references, clearly.